# Polygon: Solidity build failed for 'pragma solidity ^0.8.7' with chainlink

Tags: blockchain, polygon, solidity, chainlink, matic

In polygon chain, the latest chainlink version not support.

If I remove chainlink library, it deploy sucessfully.

Chainlink 0.8 working fine in 'ropston test' network. But in 'Mumbai test net', not able to deploy contract.

hardhat.config.js [edit:1]
[image]

error log:
[image]

remix error log:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the contract with Remix Ide Online, web3 connection with Metamask.
Can you share your hardhat config file or error logs?
This should be inside your hardhat env.

```
    mumbai: {
  url: "https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today",
  // url: API_URL, //or Infura API  URL   
  accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    gasPrice: 10000000000,
    gasLimit: 9000000
},
```

Edit: It's failing because cant estimate gasLimit of the transaction. You can set it manually.
Inside your deploy.js script set the gasPrice and gasLimit. Depending on you are using web3js or etherjs this code will be different. This is example of another minting function.

```
FT = await contract.ownerMint(WALLET_ADDRESS,{ gasLimit: 285000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('30', 'gwei')});
```

Edit2: you can always deploy it with remix online with Metamask
[image]

Comment: I added hardhat.config.js & error log screenshots. PFA

Comment: Adding gasLimit and gasPrice should resolve the error - { gasLimit: 2850000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('30', 'gwei')}

Comment: Also tried it. But no solution found

Comment: can you share your deploy function? Make sure that your PRIVATE_KEY env variable have "0x"  or add      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],

Comment: It works, If I remove chainlink library. With chainlink, not able to deploy.

Comment: probably you are using some external API from the Chainlink, if there are any hardcoded proxy addresses link datafeed addresses - https://docs.chain.link/docs/matic-addresses/ this addresses need to be changed. you need to share your solidity code